# dmraid -r" just returns No RAID disks

Tags: centos, raid, raid-1, hp-proliant

I have installed centOS 5 on our HP Proliant ML110 GH6 server and configured the Smart Array through BIOS

Now, i would like to set up an e-mail notification with the RAID status (especially if it's failed).  When I searched through the packages available I found this one:

"dmraid-events-logwatch-1.0.0.rc13-63.el5.x86_64 - dmraid logwatch-based email reporting"

which is basically what I need.

So I installed it & I searched regarding this dmraid tool & found this "dmraid -r" command which gives you the details of your RAID.

Unfortunately mine gives me "No RAID disks".

I also went over this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidDebug but I got stuck when it tells you to try & find the metadata yourself :/

Any help is much appreciated!!

---

Result of "fdisk -l":

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14       60801   488279610   8e  Linux LVM
```

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       60801   488384001   8e  Linux LVM
```

Comment: I may be completly wrong but your not using fake raid your using real RAID, So wouldnt the OS just see this a single disk.  Im not definite on this as I heard that some "Hardware Raids" arnt actually the real  thing.

Comment: @Steve Martin - I'm not really an expert regarding RAID types (fake, hardware, software) so I just searched over the internet to find some help and that's one of the links I found.  I don't think that the OS is actually seeing 1 disk because I can both check hdparm -I /dev/sda & hdparm -I /dev/sdb

Comment: I had a conversation with a friend a couple months ago and he was saying that linux sees through a "Fake Hardware" and will show 2 disks where as windows would show just one disk, Can you post the output of fdisk -l (as super user)

Comment: question updated

Comment: Steve has hit the nail on the head - the Proliant Smart Array Controller is managing the array and presenting a 'disk' to CentOS, so there's nothing for dmraid to see. You might have some luck with the tools on the following page, but the drivers are allegedly being deprecated. http://cciss.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If the Proliant Smart Array Controller is doing the job, how come when I load the HP ACU (Array Configuration Utility) it's telling me 'No Controller found'?

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of RAID atm:

1. Real hardware RAID cards, which need their own driver and show a single disk to the OS. Forexample a smartarray in an HP.
2. Software RAID. E.g. `md` under Linux.
3. Fake RAID (which is software RAID with some assitance from the BIOS). Example IRST which is detected as `dm` under Linux.

The tools you installed are for this [dmraid](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmraid) while you are using a smartarray hardware RAID controller. This is why the tool finds my fake RAID installations and why you get this error.